# switch case is always returning undefined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a switch case that returns random quotes from an array of facts/quotes
and it's always giving me undefined  although the switch case has no syntax errors

```
  let fact;
const rand=  Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
console.log(rand)
switch(rand) {
  case 0:
    fact=facts[0]
    break;
  case 1:
      fact=facts[1]
    break;
  case 2:
     fact= facts[2]
      break;
  case 3:
     fact= facts[3]
      break;
  case 4:
     fact= facts[4]
      break;
  case 5:
     fact= facts[5]
      break;
  case 6:
      fact=facts[6]
      break;
  case 7:
      fact=facts[7]
      break;
  case 8:
     fact= facts[8]   
      break;
      default:
    fact = "dino random fact";

}
```

here I tried to log it to console:

```
    tile.classList.add("grid-item");
   tile.innerHTML=`<h3>${dinosaur.species}</h3>
                  
                   <p> ${console.log(fact)} </p>
                   <img src="images/${dinosaur.species}.png">
                  
                   `;
```

Comment: do you have a `facts` array?

Comment: Please do not use this switch statement, just use `fact=facts[rand]`.

Comment: The least error prone solution would be `const fact = facts[Math.floor(Math.random() * facts.length)]`. If you goal is simply to select a random element from an array, that is.

Comment: yes, this is because you are trying to acces to a position of your array that does not have a value, and that is why is returning you **undefined**

Comment: the facts array is returned from the dom so I didn't include it, we can use a smaller array with dummy data for testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the random value as index and take the default as exceptional value.

```js
const
    facts = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight']
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),
    fact = rand === 9
        ?  "dino random fact"
        : facts[rand];

console.log(fact);
```

Answer (score 1):

facts does not exists so when you set fact = facts[something]

fact is undefined

Comment: They exist but I didn't include them in the post